# Apache redirect to another server keeping browser address

Tags: wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite, cross-domain

A have a custom website based on apache/php. I also have a wordpress blog and I would like it to be hosted in a different server.

I have tried to create a sub-domine like http://blog.mydomine.com but i would like to keep the old address (http://www.mydomine.com/corp/blog) for SEO purposes. I added the following configuration tu my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/corp/blog 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://blog.mydomine.com/$1 [L]
```

I would like to know if I can tell apache not to change the browser address after redirect the request. I know that I could do a 301 redirection but i would prefer to keep the old address.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!! :)

Answer (score 3):

Use the P flag
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://blog.mydomine.com/$1 [P]
```

Comment: I just tried and I got the following error: 

`Proxy Error

The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /corp/blog/.

Reason: DNS lookup failure for: ...`

Answer (score 3):

You could try a reverse proxy...

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost on
ProxyPass /corp/blog http://blog.mydomine.com/
ProxyPassReverse /corp/blog http://blog.mydomine.com/
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /corp/blog /
```

This requires [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) be installed and enabled.
Note that this will only work in the following contexts per the apache doc: server config, virtual host, directory - this means that putting it in a htaccess file won't work.

Comment: Just one question. Should this code be placed on the sub-domine server?

Comment: this should be placed in the (i'm assuming) VirtualHost entry within your httpd.conf (or hopefully your vhost.conf or similar within the conf.d dir) of the subdomain apache webhost, i have updated the code to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

What you're wanting isn't really possible. It's not Apache that's displaying the address, it's the web browser, and there's no way (thankfully) to tell a web browser "go to site A, but tell the user it's site B."

You could fake this behavior using a frame page on your main site, but since you're wanting this for SEO I don't think that would help.

Comment: This is partly incorrect in that, as mentioned in the other answers, a reverse proxy could in fact deliver content from site a when a request comes in for site b.